# How to create a modern Windows "Open Folder" dialog with Python

Tags: python, winapi

For several hours now, I have been trying to open the modern folder selection dialog using python.

My application is currently using pywebview's [create_file_dialog](https://pywebview.flowrl.com/examples/open_file_dialog.html). Which works as intended, but it's really not very convient for the user. See picture below.

[image]

What I would like, is this one:

[image]

Besides looking nicer and having a much more intuative design, it also uses the last selected path as the initial selection.

I have tried to use pywin32, but I have not found a way to create this exact dialog (only different forms of the default file selection dialog).

From my research I'd say that I probably need the [IFileOpenDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileopendialog). But there seems to be no way to use IFileOpenDialog using Python, or is there?

Does anyone know how to create said dialog?

Comment: As an aside, I can't recommend PySimpleGUI more if you're only needing a GUI... I've run into trouble using the folder dialog because despite still being around for things, it seems like MS Windows has dropped all support in modern frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Alex Guteniev for pointing me in the right direction!

Here is what I ended up using (copied mostly from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52617785/4934061)):

*PLEASE NOTE: This solution is not perfect. The created IModalDialog has no parent. So if you have a Python GUI running, this dialog will not be forced in front and can even be closed after the main window is closed.*

###### WinDialogs.h

```cpp
#pragma once
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) wchar_t * open_folder_dialog();
```

###### WinDialogs.cpp

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "WinDialogs.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <atlbase.h>  // for CComPtr, CComHeapPtr

struct ComInit
{
    ComInit() { CoInitialize(nullptr); }
    ~ComInit() { CoUninitialize(); }
};

wchar_t * open_folder_dialog() {
    // Initialize COM to be able to use classes like IFileOpenDialog.
    ComInit com;

    // Create an instance of IFileOpenDialog.
    CComPtr<IFileOpenDialog> pFolderDlg;
    pFolderDlg.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog);

    // Set options for a filesystem folder picker dialog.
    FILEOPENDIALOGOPTIONS opt{};
    pFolderDlg->GetOptions(&opt);
    pFolderDlg->SetOptions(opt | FOS_PICKFOLDERS | FOS_PATHMUSTEXIST | FOS_FORCEFILESYSTEM);

    // Show the dialog modally.
    if (SUCCEEDED(pFolderDlg->Show(nullptr)))
    {
        // Get the path of the selected folder and output it to the console.

        CComPtr<IShellItem> pSelectedItem;
        pFolderDlg->GetResult(&pSelectedItem);

        CComHeapPtr<wchar_t> pPath;
        pSelectedItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pPath);

        return pPath.m_pData;
    }
    // Else dialog has been canceled. 

    // The destructor of ComInit calls CoUninitialize() here after all
    // other objects have been destroyed.
    return NULL;
}
```

###### Python

```py
import ctypes

mydll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("WinDialogs.dll")
mydll.open_folder_dialog.restype = ctypes.c_wchar_p
print(mydll.open_folder_dialog())
```

Comment: Smart pointers are awesome, but they can outsmart you, too. `pPath.m_pData` is a dangling pointer by the time `open_folder_dialog()` returns control to the caller. Every time you cross a `}` C++ initiates a garbage collector run.

Comment: @IInspectable Good catch! C++ is not at all my strength, how could this be fixed? Also feel free to edit.

Comment: The fix is simple: [`return pPath.Detach();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/cheapptrbase-class#detach). But that also transfers responsibility for cleanup to the caller. Best to implement a Python wrapper that assigns the return value to a Python string and releases the memory.

Comment: There's also a latent bug in the `ComInit` class: The c'tor can fail, but the d'tor will run either way, potentially calling `CoUninitialize()` without a previous **successful** call to `CoInitialize()`. There is no one correct way to fix this. And while I was thinking up a simple solution, I spotted another bug: `CComPtr::CoCreateInstance()` can fail, and if it does the subsequent invocation of `operator->()` will attempt to dereference a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not impossible -- see [Access COM methods from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48986244/2945027) as an example how to use an arbitrary COM interface in Python.

It requires very careful work to port `IFileOpenDialog` like an interface in that answer, and mistakes likely to result in crashes.

---

Note that Python has an easy way to access COM objects, like

```
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch('Program.Name')
```

But it only works for `IDispatch`-based interfaces, and `IFileOpenDialog` isn't such.

---

Instead of trying to use `IFileOpenDialog` directly from Python, I'd recommend creating a wrapper in a language that can easily use `IFileOpenDialog` directly, that is in C++, and putting that in a DLL you'll use from Python.

Comment: Yes, creating a DLL seems to be the only feasible option here. It's crazy to me that there seems to be no established solution to this problem. I also looked at the COM objects, but holy hell, that is a whole nother set of problems.